# What it means that we can verify solution of knapsack problem in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem, np

knapsack problem is NP means that there is polynomial algorithm that can verify solution. Can you tell me what means "verify". what is that algorithm? How we can verify given solution?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a victim of sloppy language.

The classes P and NP apply to *decision* problems only.  Those are questions with a yes/no answer.

NP does not mean that we verify an answer in polynomial time, because that answer is just 'yes' or 'no'.

NP means that every 'yes' answer has a *proof* that we can verify in polynomial time.

For knapsack, the NP decision problem is "is there a subset of weights that exactly fills the knapsack"?   When the answer is 'yes', a list of those weights would be the proof, and you can verify it just by adding them up.

Answer (score 0):

Verify means checking if an answer is correct.

To verify a solution to the knapsack problem (e.g. a set of items to pack) we can sum their sizes (linear to the number of items packed) and compare the total to the space in the knapsack.

Verifying that it is an optimal answer is as difficult (np) as solving the knapsack problem.  However, given a set of solutions we can choose (or verify) the best of those solutions again in polynominal time to the number of solutions.

Comment: But if the sum of the weights of these items is less than or equal to the weight of the knapsack does it mean that this is the correct answer? Could there be another set of items whose sum of weights is still less than or equal to the capacity of the knapsack, but the sum of the values is greater than the first set?